# Moving polygons to points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, editing

I have a polygon shapefile that corresponds to a point shapefile in the same projection.  I need to move the polygons so that the vertices line up with the points.  Right now they are about 3 feet off as someone shifted them by accident and saved. Is there a way to do this by snapping the vertex from one of the polygons to the point that it is associated with?

Comment: Using which software?

Comment: what are the projections?

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2.  They are the same projections.  Someone shifted them by accident and saved.

Comment: Some or all polygon features.  If all are they moved in the same direction?

Answer (score 2):

Add the [spatial adjustment toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m800000030000000). Then open an edit session, create some links from the vertices of 4 of the polygons to the points, select affine transform and run the adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I am assuming you can identify which polygons were affected (be it a few or all), they were *only* shifted (no rotation or scaling), and are currently in an edit session. Ensure Point and Vertex snapping are enabled.

1. Select all affected polygons and locate the selection anchor (small
   x near center of all selected elements).
2. While holding the Ctrl key, hover the cursor over the [anchor until
   the cursor changes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/by_dragging_and_snapping_to_another_feature/01m800000033000000/). Click and drag the anchor to a polygon vertex
   for which there is a matching point. Release both mouse and Ctrl
   key.
3. Clicking somewhere on the selected elements (so as not to deselect
   everything), drag the polygons such that the anchor snaps to the
   desired point. Depending on your Sticky Move Tolerance setting and current zoom, you
   may need to drag everything further away than the desired point
   before it will move.